# Connection refused at own SMTP on the server

Tags: php, connection, phpmailer

I am writing a script to send emails, but unfortunately there is a small problem that prevents me from further work. I do everything according to the documentation of both PhpMailer and my server service provider (SMTP server address is the web address of port 587). On the mailer's side everything is fine too. Unfortunately, when I try to send an e-mail I receive information of this type:

SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)

What's wrong?

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'phpmailer/exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/phpmailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/smtp.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'kameal-design.xaa.pl';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->UserName = 'welcome@kameal-design.xaa.pl';
$mail->Password = '******';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->setFrom('welcome@kameal-design.xaa.pl');
$mail->addAddress('example@gmail.com');
$mail->addReplyTo('welcome@kameal-design.xaa.pl');
$mail->addCC('cc@kameal-design.xaa.pl');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@kameal-design.xaa.pl');

$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'test subject';
$mail->Body = 'this is the html message body in <b>bold</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'this is the body for plain text, when user doesn"t use correctly mail browser';

$mail->send();
```

Comment: From the machine running this code see if you can telnet to the host on 587, if that fails its a network issue. Check any hw/sw firewalls.

Comment: try to do 'telnet kameal-design.xaa.pl 587' and check connection is building or not

Comment: @AlexK.Theoretically, I connected to telnet and I received a message that this system is not intended for sending unwanted or mass messages. So the problem lies not with the firewall or the client computer

Comment: FWIW, I can't reach that server. That "unwanted" message is just a welcome banner, and means you have connected. Are you testing that from the same computer your script is running on?

Comment: @Synchro exactly

Comment: I have seen cases where you have to whitelist the servers that are allowed to send email through the SMTP server.  What do the SMTP server logs show?  Nothing, error, ... ?